# Reading or Unloading quantum data to classical data

Tags: measurement

I have a very basic question: say I perform some set of operations on $N$ qubits (like QFT, QFT addition etc), and thus have a $N$ qubit final state.

If each qubit has something that I want to read off of it, is it possible to extract data from each qubit into classical?

I now know how to load classical data onto a quantum device, but how do I read the final data? Is it impossible to get it since the wavefunction collapses? What I mean to ask is whether there exists a general protocol to read final N qubits into N classical bits (even at least by repeated measurements (bounded by the Chernoff limit) or similar such methods).

Comment: measurements involve irreversible loss of information, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you have an algorithm that can prepare a state such as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert 0A\rangle+\vert 1B\rangle),$$

and you want to be able to extract $A$ and $B$ separately.

You are correct that if you measure the second register, you will "collapse" the state, and it may be difficult to distinguish $A$ and $B$.

However, you may still be able to determine whether $A=B$. For example, interference allows you to measure the first register in the Hadamard basis.  If $A=B$ then after Hadamarding the first register must revert back to $0$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. This is exactly what I am talking about. So, you seem to conclude that it wouldn't, in principle be possible to go from (|0A> + |0B>) to |AB> right?

Comment: You can repeat the measurement and get a probability distribution. In case states $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal in some basis, you can distinguish them easily as one is mapped to $|0\rangle$ and second one to $|1\rangle$ after measurement (I assume that $A$ and $B$ are single qubit states). Otherwise, you have to employ quantum tomography to "scan" the states.

Answer (score 1):

In Qiskit, to read the qubits into classical bits you can use the `measure` operation. If you have defined classical and quantum registers as `cr` and `qr` respectively, you can get the values of all the qubits by doing `qc.measure(qr,cr)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Well, what I am looking for is something like : say I have a 2 qubit state such as |0A> + |1B> and I want to read both A and B into classical registers. Then if I measure the second qubit, system will collapse to A or B.

Comment: Do you mean get the state vector out? This can be done using the statevector simulator. You load this in the same way as the qasm simulator ` Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')`. If you then want to get the counts, you should do this using a separate execution

Comment: @met927 this seems to address *classical* simulation of a *quantum* algorithm, but not to the OP's question about reading out both $A$ and $B$ from a superposition of $\vert 0A\rangle+\vert 1B\rangle$.